# To hide or show div depending on checkbox click in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

In my view, I have a table where each row contain checkbox and 2 columns. Initially it is not checked

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="a" data-id="@item.Data.CandidatePortfolioID" onclick="Checked()" />
        <div class="cell" id="edit2" style="width:auto;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataEndDate)</div>
        <div class="cell" id="edit1" style="width:auto; display:none;">
         @Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.DataEndDate, new { @class = "date"})
                </div>
```

I want the div with id='edit1' to be shown when the checkbox is checked and hide it otherwise for that Particular row

how can i do so?

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[name='chkbox']").on("change", function () {
    $("#edit1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Pre jQuery 1.7:

```
$("input[name='chkbox']").change(function () { // or .bind("change", function () {
    $("#edit1").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/quMfQ/)

Comment: Try the pre jQuery 1.7 solution then, that's why I threw it in.

Comment: I tried ..now its working but not in way i want...it always show that for first row, even if i select 3rd row....I want the selected row's corresponding column to be hide/show....in my table

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.a').click(function() 
{
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
         $('div#edit1').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('div#edit1').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.a').click(function(){

if ($('.a').is(':checked'))
{
 $('#edit1').css('display','block');
}
else
{
$('#edit1').css('display','none');
}
});​
```

here is the working demo [checkbox](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2X4Y/1/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){

if ($(this).is(':checked'))
 {
 $(this).next().next().show();
 }
else
{
$(this).next().next().hide();
}
});​
```

Comment: it givs me this error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Function expected"

Comment: :Bt its not working stil!!
I dont get any error but it is not doing anytihng
also I want the selected row's corresponding column to be hide/show....in my table....not just for first row

Answer (score 0):

Make it check box specific with "name" attribute:

```
$('inpunt[name="chkbox"]').bind('click',function(){ 
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
{
     $('div#edit1').hide();
}
else
{
    $('div#edit1').show();
}
});
```

Comment: It's not working, I want to show date picker of the selected row , bt using all the above ans, it is showing me date picker either in first row or in all rows
Can u help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Thanx for all ur help and guidence
In my code i made following changes:
in the view code

```
   <div class="cell" style="width:auto;"> <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" class="a"  data-id="@item.Data.CandidatePortfolioID" onclick="checkbox1(@item.Index)"/> 
</div> 
       <div class="cell" id=**"edit2-@item.Index"** style="width:auto;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EndDate)</div>
        <div class="cell" id=**"edit1-@item.Index"** style="width:auto; display:none;">@Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.EndDate, new { @class = "date" })</div>
```

****JQuery Function****

```
   function checkbox1(index) {
    var divname =index;
    $("#edit1-" + divname).toggle();
    $("#edit2-" + divname).toggle();
}
```